# Netgear UTM9s causes network drop off when port forwarding

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding

Our company just installed a Netgear UTM9S and I've been trying to get our server visible to the outside world.

I've gone into firewall settings and set up a new rule that states all incoming HTTP traffic be forwarded onto `192.168.1.82:8881`.

For a while the server is visible when visiting the building IP address from both on and off the network, but for some reason our internet will cut off after about 10 minutes and the firewall admin panel is not available. The only thing that can be done is to power cycle the firewall and delete the rule.

I'm pretty new to networking in general, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to Netgear support about this issue, it seems as if it's related to out of date firmware. Updating to the latest firmware fixed the problem.

It is worth noting that the units do not come shipped with the latest firmware (standard practice, I know), you will need a support license to upgrade this though. Something to keep in mind if you buy the unit second hand, or not from a Netgear reseller.